# What is the maximum number of different values for a specific text parameter in one event?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

When setting parameter reporting for custom events, if you choose parameter type as text, is there a limit how many different values can this text parameter have?
Here is an example with four different text values:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each individual event has only one value for the parameter. But (as far as I know) there is no limit to the number of different values that can be reported across events.